# Facebook Graph Api filter feed by category

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filter, feed, categories

Does anyone know how to filter a users feed by category using the graph api? For instance.... I would like to pull the users news feed that relates to only Music like

http://graph.facebook.com/me/home?from_category=Music

Any help would be much appreciated.... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

as much I know, there is no direct way to query graph api for getting filtered feed though if you know the filter_key for a particular filter type of a user stream,then you can query the graph api with identifier filter.
so I think

1) you will need to make FQL query to get filter key, with something like: 
  `SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=<uid>` you can get all the avalable filters from a user's stream. please refer the [doc here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/)

2) now when you have your desired `filter_key` then you can request graph api to get the filterd feed with `GET me/home?filter=filter_key` . checkout the corresponding [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home)

Answer (score -3):

Simply use

me?fields=id,name,**music**.limit(100)