# How do I use stream_filter with a me/feed Graph API request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In Facebook's Graph API reference, the page [**/{user-id}/feed**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/) specifies in its "Reading" section that a possible modifier is **filter** of type "string". It points to the [**stream_filter**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter/) reference table, too.

I'm having trouble understanding what a stream_filter does and how I use it in a request to the Graph API. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest, i searched for those filters too and found out that there is a thread about it already with a good answer: [Facebook Graph Api filter feed by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203798/facebook-graph-api-filter-feed-by-category)

So this is how i get the available filters by FQL:

```
SELECT name, type, filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me()
```

Try this in the Graph API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20name%2C%20filter_key%2C%20type%20FROM%20stream_filter%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29

Now when i try /me/home?filter=x and replace the x with my photo filter, i do get a different result than without a filter. When i try this with /me/feed there is no difference, i get status messages without any photo too. Maybe it just does not work for the feed connection...Although it is mentioned in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/

More information:

- [Filter_Key by Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749357/filter-key-by-application)
- [Facebook Graph API: How to filter home & feed by application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910725/facebook-graph-api-how-to-filter-home-feed-by-application/8874108#8874108)

Comment: Are these `filter_key`s created by the user? It's still not clear what I use these for.

Comment: i included a link to the graph api explorer. as far as i can see only the filters with type "friendlist" are user generated, there are also filters for photos, videos and stuff.

Comment: So it's basically just the [left sidebar on Facebook](http://i.imgur.com/41gpQda.jpg), then. Got it...